# Laravel user specific caching

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I've never done much with caching, but am trying to play around with it a bit now. I have a dashboard that returns a lot of data, and to make the load a bit lighter, I am caching data like so:

```
return cache()->rememberForever('something', function () {
    return auth()->user()->something()->get();
});
```

Where "something" is just a related model. When creating a new record, in the controller `store` and `update` methods I just do this:

```
cache()->forget('something');
```

This all works flawlessly. But when I login with another user, all cached data from the previous user is obviously being displayed on the dashboard.

Is there an easy way to simply cache data per user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something like this to store user object for each user separately:

```
return cache()->rememberForever('something' . auth()->id(), function () {
    return auth()->user()->something()->get();
});
```

To get the data for an authenticated user:

```
 cache('something' . auth()->id());
```

Answer (score -1):

Caching per user does not necessarily make much sense that I can think of off the top of my head (not to say there isn't the odd use-case out there for this). The purpose of caching is not to be a "session"-store for a given user, but lighten the load across the entire application for all users.

I would start by asking why you need to cache per user. Perhaps there is a fundamental misunderstanding as to how Laravel Caching works, or perhaps the application architecture is poorly designed? My recommendation is to cache everything but user-related information.

There are several packages out there that can help with this, I have created one to scratch my own itch: https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-model-caching. This package aims to abstract caching out and automatically cache database interactions (except the user information) for you. This takes all the WHERE clause conditions into account, so each query would be cached differently for different WHERE clauses. This means that your user-sensitive data will be returned only for the correct user (as presumably the user ID or some other identifier would be in the WHERE clause).

Comment: Well, I created a "finance admin" panel, and on my dashboard I load a lot of stuff. Which are a lot of queries each time the dashboard is being displayed. Which is why I want to cache stuff. But yeah perhaps it's not what caching is meant for and maybe I should look for alternatives :)

Comment: @Hardist I think you have a reasonable use case for caching; there's no need to fetch and recompute data when it will produce the same result. Mike's answer seems contradictory by recommending to not cache user-related info but then his package does cache that info instead of ignoring WHERE clauses with user IDs.

Comment: I think there may be some misunderstanding of what I meant above. "Caching Per User" is a specific use case where each user would have a different cache store. That is what I meant that was not needed. Of course you would cache information that has user data in it, but the cache would not be tied to the user, as we only need to cache what the queries return, regardless of the user performing them.

Comment: I completely disagree with @mike.bronner. Each user may require different caching. There are a lot of use cases for that. Let say, your application uses remote services and multiple API calls are made from the application, and also the responses are completely different for each user. Just think what Cloudflare does, once you login to a site that is cached by CF, you should not see other user's profile data rather only yours, tagging cached data with user's session or id or something that uniquely identifies the user is completely necessary. And this use-case is one of the biggest use-cases.