# Laravel Caching with time filters

Tags: laravel, caching

Given I am caching a query in laravel:

```
return Cache::remember('posts.all', 20, function(){
         return Post::all();
});
```

All fine.

My question is what if I want to apply filtering on the posts example get posts for last week

```
Post::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
```

What if user selects a different date from the time picker example last month how that will work with caching ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll do that, the same cached result will be given to all users. If you want to [cache user specific data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48037332/1227923), you need to add user ID to the key:

```
Cache::remember('posts.all.' . auth()->id(), 20, function() use($from, $to) {
     return Post::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
});
```

Then to get the data:

```
cache('posts.all.' . auth()->id())
```

**Update**

To make Laravel refresh the cached query result, you also need to cache from and to dates and check these.

```
if (cache('from' . auth().id()) !== $from || cache('to' . auth().id()) !== $to) {
    Cache::forget('posts.all.' . auth().id());
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand that caching user specific data it was more of a generic example on trying to explain what my question was, what If I cache the data from last week what will happen with older data? Is the caching gonna perform a query all the time when the date its not the same ?